# How to wget recursively on specific TLDs?

Tags: recursion, dns, wget, tld

Is it possible to recursively download files from specific TLDs with wget?

Specifically, I'm trying to download the full text of the [Code of Massachusetts Regulations](http://www.lawlib.state.ma.us/source/mass/cmr/index.html). The actual text of the regulations is stored in multiple files across multiple domains—so I'd like to start the recursive download from the [index page](http://www.lawlib.state.ma.us/source/mass/cmr/index.html), but only follow links to .gov and .us domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from the [wget documentation on spanning hosts](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Spanning-Hosts.html#Spanning-Hosts), I was able to make this work with the -H and -D flags:

```
wget -r -l5 -H -D.us,.gov http://www.lawlib.state.ma.us/source/mass/cmr/index.html
```